# How to fill all data rows of a table with the same value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Say I have Column1 and Column2.

I want to fill Column1 and Column2 with "Text1" and "Text2" for a certain number of records.

Is there any way I can achieve this without looping through each data row? I was wondering if there was any performance-efficient way to do this.

Right now, I am using:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   row["Column1"] = "Text1";
   row["Column2"] = "Text2";
}
```

But if I had something like 50k rows, that loop would take a very long time. Any way to reduce that time?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you have any condition for update value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a certain number of rows:

```
update top 10 dt
    set column1 = 'text1',
        column2 = 'text2';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CTE` to do this.

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT TOP N *
         FROM   Yourtable
         ORDER  BY somecolumn)
UPDATE CTE
SET    column1 = 'text1',
       column2 = 'text2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Take(10))
{
   row["Column1"] = "Text1";
   row["Column2"] = "Text2";
}
```

or you can use a simple `for` loop like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  var row = rows[i]; 
}
```